# PlayFab SDK Unreal Source Build, plugin doesn´t want to install

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine5, playfab

I hope you are doing well. A few days ago, I downloaded the Unreal 5.3.2 source build. After successfully installing and building the engine, I copied the PlayFab SDK from my Unreal Engine Epic Games version 5.3.2 to the source code version. I simply copied the 'Marketplace' folder from 'Plugins' in the Unreal Engine source to the 'Plugins' folder. Then I tried to rebuild the Unreal Engine 5 source, but I encountered numerous errors. Here is the output from Visual Studio 2022 during the build process, thanks!:

```
 Build started at 15:34...
 1>------ Build started: Project: UE5, Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------
 1>Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
 1>Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -Target="UnrealEditor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild
 1>Log file: C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
 1>Invalidating makefile for UnrealEditor (PlayFab.uplugin has been added)
 1>Parsing headers for UnrealEditor
 1>  Running Internal UnrealHeaderTool UnrealEditor C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Development\UnrealEditor.uhtmanifest -WarningsAsErrors
 1>Total of 106 written
 1>Reflection code generated for UnrealEditor in 98.6431302 seconds
 1>Invalidating makefile for ShaderCompileWorker (PlayFab.uplugin has been added)
 1>Building UnrealEditor and ShaderCompileWorker...
 1>Using Visual Studio 2022 14.36.32543 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
 1>Determining max actions to execute in parallel (4 physical cores, 8 logical cores)
 1>  Executing up to 4 processes, one per physical core
 1>  Requested 1.5 GB memory per action, 314.97 MB available: limiting max parallel actions to 1
 1>------ Building 42 action(s) started ------
 1>[1/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCommon.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCommon\Public\PlayFabCommonSettings.h(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabRuntimeSettings.h': No such file or directory
 1>[2/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.6.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[3/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.4.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[4/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.2.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[5/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.10.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[6/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.8.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[7/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.5.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[8/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.9.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[9/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.1.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[10/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.7.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[11/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFabCpp.3.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[12/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.14.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[13/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.15.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[14/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.23.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[15/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.17.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[16/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.18.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[17/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.9.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[18/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.20.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Private\PlayFabPrivate.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFab/Public/IPlayFab.h': No such file or directory
 1>[19/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.5.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[20/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.4.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[21/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.3.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[22/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.13.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[23/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.6.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[24/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.19.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[25/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.1.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[26/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.22.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[27/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.11.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[28/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.7.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[29/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.10.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[30/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.2.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[31/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.12.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[32/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.21.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[33/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.8.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>[34/42] Compile [x64] Module.PlayFab.16.cpp
 1>C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory
 1>Total time in Parallel executor: 67.23 seconds
 1>Total execution time: 296.34 seconds
 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3073: The command "..\..\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UnrealEditor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.
 1>Done building project "UE5.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
 ========== Build completed at 15:39 and took 05:06,254 minutes ==========
```

-and here are my errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State    Details
     Error    MSB3073    The command "..\..\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UnrealEditor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.    UE5    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets    44        
     Error        Project "C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\UnrealEngine.csproj.props" was not imported by "C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\ScriptPlugin\Source\ScriptGeneratorUbtPlugin\ScriptGeneratorUbtPlugin.ubtplugin.csproj" at (3,3), due to the file not existing.    ScriptGeneratorUbtPlugin.ubtplugin    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\UnrealEngine-release\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Programs\Shared\UnrealEngine.csproj.props    3        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabRuntimeSettings.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCommon\Public\PlayFabCommonSettings.h    9        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFabCpp\Public\Core\PlayFabCppBaseModel.h    13        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFab/Public/IPlayFab.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Private\PlayFabPrivate.h    24        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8        
     Error    C1083    Cannot open include file: 'PlayFabCommon/Public/PlayFabAuthenticationContext.h': No such file or directory    UE5    C:\Users\flueg\Downloads\MU5\UE5M\Engine\Plugins\PlayFabSDK\Source\PlayFab\Classes\PlayFabRequestCommon.h    8
```